# Choclatey not working

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

When i use Choclatey to install anything like **choco install flashplayerplugin**. I receive follwinf error:

```
Chocolatey v0.10.3
Installing the following packages:
flashplayerplugin
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
flashplayerplugin not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists 
but the version does not.
 Version: ""
 Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - flashplayerplugin - flashplayerplugin not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists 
but the version does not.
 Version: ""
 Source(s): "https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/"
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see something like this, you should first check to rule out proxies that would block this particular location.

About 90% of the time, you need to set up your proxy.

If it is not that, you can always use Fiddler to determine what the issue may be.

Also, this is best asked over at Super User or Server Fault (as this question is being voted to close b/c not about development) or reaching out on the prescribed Chocolatey channels (Gitter or email). HTH

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that chocolatey is not able to connect to the remote server. In my case problem happened because the proxy configuration of Nuget package manager. I solved problem doing following : 1. Find NuGet.Config file . NuGet.Config may be at different location based on a version of NuGet. In my case it was located at %appdata%\NuGet. You can find it by searching "NuGet.Config"  inside C drive.  2 Open NuGet.Config file make sure that proxy configuration is correct or is cleared in case of no proxy is needed. In my case as once I configured NuGet proxy that was not needed any more. Because I wasn't working behind the proxy. So I removed proxy section :

```
<configuration>
    <!-- stuff -->
    <config>
        <add key="http_proxy" value="http://192.168.7.7:3128" />
        <add key="https_proxy" value="http://192.168.7.7:3128" />
    </config>
    <!-- stuff -->
```

So remove proxy config tag or correct proxy values.
3. Saved changes restarted cmd and ran choco install command again and everything worked well. Hope this will help you too.

Comment: Hi, I configured the proxy settings in Nuget.config but still i get the same error.

Comment: Is it something specific to a package or error happens when installing any package ?